# Does the sequence of operators $(A_nx)(t) = x(t^{1+\frac{1}{n}}) $converge by norm?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

I have a simple question:

The question is as follows:

Consider the sequence of operators $A_n:C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ as follows:

$$ (A_nx)(t) = x(t^{1+\frac{1}{n}})$$
Prove that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $A_n$ is a linear bounded operator. Show that $A_n \rightarrow I$ strongly. Does it converge by norm? Justify.

$\textbf{Notation and information}$

I refer you to the answer by "user438666", for to get information about the notations in the question.

I really cannot make connection with the defined operators!

Can someone help me to understand it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you state uniform convergence? It is not clear what you mean by is not zero.

Comment: @johnMa I mean that when the sup of the difference which is the uniform norm of the difference; not goes to zero when $n$ goes to $\infty$, it shows that our sequence of functions in not uniformly convergent to identity function. I I am not wrong?

Comment: Can you write down the equation in the question (you can edit your question, using the "edit" right below your question)?

Comment: @JohnMa I am not writing that in the statement of the question, because as I wrote, I am not sure about it! If you think that I am right, please feel free to add it there. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot well if you are right. Indeed it is not clear to me you know the definition at all. Did you have notes about the definition?

Comment: I would think what you call uniform convergence is really strong convergence of the operators sequence $A_n$, but I might be misinterpreting your question. To me uniform convergence would be on the operator norm, i.e. the supremum of $A_n(f)$ for all $f$ such that $|| f||=1$ where $||\cdot||$ is the sup norm

Comment: @JohnMa I know the definition of the uniform norm. It is $||X(t)||_{\infty} = sup_{t \in [0,1]} |X(t)|$. So it is strongly convergent if $||(A_nx)(t) - (Ix)(t)|| \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ and it is said uniformly convergent if $||A_n - I||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$  when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @user438666 But I think, since here we work on $C[0,1]$ so we have to consider the infinity norm?

Comment: One possibility, I think is to differentiate for to find its supremum?

Comment: I think @user438666 is correct - in this context, strong convergence means that $A_nx\to x$ for every $x\in C([0,1])$. But because the topology on $C([0,1])$ is that of the sup norm, this is the same as requiring that $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A_nx(t)-x(t)|\to0$ for all $x\in C([0,1])$. Norm convergence, on the other hand, means that we have that convergence of the previous expression is uniform over all $x\in C([0,1])$ satisyfing $\|x\|_\infty\le1$, which seems very unlikely to be true.

Comment: @Jason I messed up the definition of the norm, of course I meant $\leq 1$ and not $=1$ for the norm of $f$.

Comment: @user438666 Actually, the two definitions are equivalent!

Comment: Ya Thanks! I also wanted to point that. Because we work on a compact set $[0,1]$ and it can be restricted to closed unit ball

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that, I'll try to think about why that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|A_n(f) - f\|_\infty = 0$ for each $f\in C = C([0,1]).$

Proof: Verify that $t^{1 + 1/n} \to t$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ (You can use calculus to see the maximum value of $t-t^{1 + 1/n}$ occurs at $1/(1+1/n)^n.$)

Let $f \in C, \epsilon>0.$ Because $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1],$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x,y \in [0,1], |x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$ Because $t^{1 + 1/n} \to t$ uniformly, we can choose $N$ such that $|t^{1 + 1/n} -t | < \delta $ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $n\ge N.$ For such $n$ we have

$$\|A_n(f) - f\|_\infty = \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t^{1 + 1/n})-f(t)| \le \sup_{x,y\in [0,1],|x-y| < \delta}|f(x)-f(y)| \le \epsilon.$$

This proves 1.

2. $A_n$ does not converge to $I$ in the operator norm. To prove this it's enough to show there exists a sequence $f_n$ in the closed unit ball of $C$ such that

$$\tag 1 \|A_n(f_n) - f_n\|_\infty \ge 1,\, n = 1,2,\dots$$

To do this, define $f_n$ to have the piecewise linear graph that joins the points $(0,0), (1/2^{n+1}, 0),$ $(1/2^n,1), (1,1).$ Then $\|f_n\|_\infty =1$ for all $n.$ We have the left side of $(1)$ at least as large as

$$|f_n((1/2^n)^{1+1/n}) - f_n(1/2^n)| = |f_n(1/2^{n+1}) - f_n(1/2^n)| = |0-1| = 1.$$

This proves $(1)$ and we are done.

Comment: Many thanks! Very clever answer! Sorry can you also show that it is linear and bounded? I just wanna see how it is done! Thanks again!

Comment: The above is the hard part. Don't you want to give the linear bounded part a try? You'll get much more out of it that way.

Comment: No I think it is an increasing sequence and it will be bounded by above by $|x(1)|$. But I am not sure. About linearity I do not know how to work with $(A_n(ax_1 + bx_2)) = (ax_1 + bx_2)(t^{1 + \frac{1}{n}})$. Because from one side it looks simple and trivial. And I always am afraid of trivial staff!

Comment: Let $t\in [0,1]$ Then $t^{1+1/n}$ is also in $[0,1].$ Hence 

$$|A_n(x)(t)| = |x(t^{1+1/n})| \le \|x\|_\infty.$$

Since $t\in [0,1]$ was arbitrary, we have $\|A_n(x)\|_\infty\le \|x\|_\infty.$ This shows $A_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clever idea!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to award but it is written that I may award your bounty in 21 hours! I will try again after 21 hours. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't worry about it. Let it go for a few days. You might see a better answer, who knows?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a solution to the problem, but just a clear up of some definitions that wouldn't fit nicely in a comment. You're confusing notions of convergence. The one you call uniform convergence is really strong convergence. This is because uniform convergence is usually the convergence in the norm of the space of the sequence, which in this case is a sequence of operators, not functions. You're dealing with a sequence of operator on a Hilbert space. One defines a norm on the space of operator $L(H)$ on a Hilbert space $H$ as

$$ ||A||=\sup\left( ||Ax||_H:x\in H, ||x||_H\leq1 \right)$$

where $||\cdot||_H$ is the norm of the Hilbert space. If $||A||<\infty$ we say that $A$ is bounded.

A sequence $A_n$ is said to be strongly convergent to $A$ iff
$$ \forall \,x\in H,\,\forall \,\varepsilon >0 \,\exists \, N\in\mathbb{N} : ||A_nx-Ax||_H<\varepsilon \,\forall \,n>N$$

notice how the convergence is defined using the norm of the Hilbert space, not of the operator space. Conversely, we say that the sequence converges uniformly to $A$ iff

$$ \forall \,\varepsilon >0 \,\exists \, N\in\mathbb{N} : ||A_n-A||<\varepsilon \,\forall \,n>N$$

Which uses directly the operator space norm.